# WIX | Remove *.config file on install

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have multiple config files (for different environments). During install user get to select the environment, and based on that correct files are copied. I want to delete the extra files that are not used. 
I am using  but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't get any errors as such, in the log I see action getting executed but files are not deleted. Can anyone please point what I am doing wrong?

```
  <Component Id="RemoveFiles" Guid="C5D634C2-744E-4CA5-BB44-F3DE88482AB5">
    <RemoveFile Id="RemoveConfigs" Name="???_*.config" On="install" />
  </Component>
```

My RemoveFile table also looks like

```
FileKey                 Component           FileName                    DirProperty InstallMode
RemoveExtraConfigFiles  RemoveExtraFiles    p6wjlh9a.con|Web_*.config   INSTALLDIR  1
```

Still it's not deleting anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RemoveFile` or `CopyFile` always run before `InstallFiles`, and it finds no files in the install directory, hence it fails.

Comment: It seems that your installation would benefit from being reorganized a bit. In case you should install just one (or some) of your config files, you should add appropriate conditions to the components holding those files, and as a result only required files (chosen by user) will be installed. This way you won't have to introduce custom actions and remove the files which were just installed. Let Windows Installer do its job properly :)

Answer (score 1):

The [RemoveFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371199.aspx) action will try to find the files you specified in the parent directory of the component, in case you don't override it in the [RemoveFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_removefile.htm) element itself (according to your sample, you don't). Make sure that it is really a folder containing that file. If the file is not found, the action won't fail - it will silently continue.

Comment: All the files are in the root folder and this component is also at the root level. I can even see the remove action present in the database. But for some reason files just won't delete. Is there anyway to log the action with full file path it's trying to delete?

Comment: I don't think so... Is this component included into the feature being installed?