# WIX - How to use RemoveFiles

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

We have multiple configuration files. Based on the environment selected, right file gets copied and the rest of the files should get deleted.
I am using `RemoveFile` but that doesn't delete anything or may be I am not using it right. Can someone give an example to delete `*.config` from `[INSTALLDIR]` during the install, after all files have been copied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WIX | Remove *.config file on install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120238/wix-remove-config-file-on-install)

Comment: Running your installation with verbose logging can give a hint why it does not remove the files: `msiexec /i product.msi /lv*x install.log`.

Answer (score 5):

In the example below `RemoveFile` is used to delete all icons (`.lnk` extension) on uninstallation, also the parent folder will be removed by using `RemoveFolder`

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DirName">
  <Component Id="cmpName" Guid="{429BC364-BE5F-4EC8-9AB9-8A522F8EC089}">
    <RemoveFile Id="removeDesktopShortcuts" On ="uninstall" Name="*.lnk"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveFolder1" On="uninstall"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score -5):

Why don't you go with option of custom action. Create a method in C# or other and then call it after 'InstallFinalize'.

Example :

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult RemoveConfigs(Session session)
{ 
    string configfiles = "\"" + session["INSTALLDIR"].ToString() + "*.config\"" ;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C del " + configfiles);

    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

In CustomAction.wxs add

```
<Custom Action="ZA_RemoveConfigs" After="InstallFinalize">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
```

Comment: This approach will fail on UAC-enabled systems. Actions after InstallFinalize run non-elevated and you can face permission denied. I'd not recommend doing it this way, yet it is an easy solution.

Comment: I am using the same and is working fine on servers where users have least access. UAC access are working fine. This will work fine also because the installation location will not be inside some OS folder like C:\Windows\system32, etc.

Comment: That's the point: it won't work if `INSTALLDIR` is the default Program Files.

Comment: Custom Action works, but i don't want to do that, just want to see if something available OOB.