# Can't delete folder WIX installer

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer, wix3.6

I have a service that is installed by my WIX installer:

```
<Component Id="cmp_myService" Guid="{5FC8815E-33T8-4C3D-9654-849EE4CB1E22}">
    <File Id="f_myService" Name="MyService.exe" Source="$(var.SourcePath)MyService.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="si_myServiceInstall" Name="My Service" DisplayName="It is my service" Type="ownProcess" Interactive="yes" Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Description="Here is some description" />
    <ServiceControl Id="sc_startStopMyService" Name="My Service" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
</Component>
```

Also, I have a custom action `ca1_removeInstallDirOnUnsinstall` that deletes a folder with all its content (`MyService.exe` is inside this folder)

```
<Custom Action="ca1_removeInstallDirOnUnsinstall" After="DeleteServices"><![CDATA[REMOVE="ALL"]]></Custom>
```

I schedule this custom action to run right after `DeleteServices` action in the execution sequence. I assume that at this point `MyService.exe` should be stopped and deleted. But I get an exception `Access to the path 'MyService.exe' is denied` which means that the service isn't deleted yet. Why does that happen and where my custom action should be scheduled to be sure that the service is already deleted?

Related log files:

```
MSI (s) (64:3C) [08:42:32:597]: Doing action: StopServices
MSI (s) (64:3C) [08:42:32:597]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 8:42:32: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 8:42:32: StopServices.
MSI (s) (64:3C) [08:42:32:597]: Doing action: DeleteServices
MSI (s) (64:3C) [08:42:32:597]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 8:42:32: StopServices. Return value 1.
Action start 8:42:32: DeleteServices.
MSI (s) (64:3C) [08:42:32:597]: Doing action: ca1_removeInstallDirOnUnsinstall
MSI (s) (64:3C) [08:42:32:597]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 8:42:32: DeleteServices. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (64:80) [08:42:32:597]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\windows\Installer\MSIA125.tmp, Entrypoint: RemoveInstallDirRecursively
MSI (s) (64:B8) [08:42:32:597]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (64:B8) [08:42:32:597]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 6176 (0x1820).
MSI (s) (64:98) [08:42:32:644]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (64:B4) [08:42:32:644]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
Action start 8:42:32: ca1_removeInstallDirOnUnsinstall.
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\windows\Installer\MSIA125.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
Calling custom action CustomAction!CustomAction.FilesAndFoldersCustomAction.RemoveInstallDirRecursively
Access to the path 'MyService.exe' is denied.
```

Comment: Deleting whole folders is rarely a good thing to do. MSI will do this on its own if the folder is empty. What kind of files are you deleting? Log files?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Yes, I'm deleting log files that are left after uninstalling process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***InstallFinalize***: **`DeleteServices`** happens before **`InstallFiles`**. I suppose **`msiexec.exe`** might have a lock on the folder for potential re-install as part of a major upgrade, but I am not sure (find locks using: [perfmon.exe](https://superuser.com/a/643312/11906), [procexp64.exe](https://superuser.com/a/399660/11906)). You can put the delete action right before **`InstallFinalize`** (which ends elevated operations that change the system). This location should work, but no guarantees. It is not good practice to "nuke" whole folders.

***Best Practice***: Generally you should not delete whole folders (it is quite risky - mess something up and you could end up deleting half your computer. Seriously. I have seen it happen. Not with MSI but with a "cleanup EXE"). I would put log files in the user profile or some other location outside of **`%ProgramFiles%`**. Or maybe use the **`event log`** or even a database to upload to online to avoid too many files left behind.

***Acceptable Remains***: In my opinion log files and other user data should not be attempted uninstalled automagically. Why? They are user data - in other words: they belong to the user. You can't just delete them summarily? I would just leave the data in place in case they want to analyze them or re-install the application (the latter is particularly important for license keys - do you leave them behind?).

***WiX***: WiX has several built-in constructs to help remove files and folders. There are the built-in MSI varieties ([**`RemoveFile`**](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html), [**`RemoveFolder`**](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefolder.html)) that just delete files by wildcard or name. Then there is the [**`RemoveFileEx`**](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html) described by [Bob Arnson (WiX developer team)](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2011/01/21/tactical-directory-nukes/). Please read the blog post. I believe it can do the job recursively (all sub folders). As you understand I don't use these constructs much since I favor other cleanup approaches. Quite frankly I just try to document the cleanup procedure in a PDF or an online KDB article.

---

***Links:***

- [wix - how to delete non-empty folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940364/wix-how-to-delete-non-empty-folder)
- [WIX - How to use RemoveFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176188/wix-how-to-use-removefiles/12000320#12000320)

Comment: It's a quite comprehensive answer. I agree to leave my log files untouched. Thank you!
P.S. I tried to schedule an action after InstallFinilize just for a test and it really works, so despite I haven't tested a locking scenario, I almost sure you are right here.

Comment: It just appears to work after `InstallFinalize`. The action will not run elevated after `InstallFinalize`, so if it tries to do something that requires elevated access it will fail. It is possible that it works when you run the whole setup elevated by launching it as an admin. The failure shows when you run the setup while a normal user account is logged in (yes, this is possible by policy or via distribution systems). After `InstallFinalize` the action becomes immediate as well - meaning it runs directly and possibly twice (depending on a few technicalities) during an installation sequence.